# Соотношение "качество — цена"

Tags: пунктуация

Каким правилом регулируется постановка тире с пробелами в сочетаниях типа "соотношение "качество — цена"?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, примерно таким же, как, например, "Футбольный матч "Динамо—Спартак". Кто-то противопоставляется кому-то.

Answer (score 0):

Вас интересуют именно пробелы? Тире *всегда* обрамляется пробелами. Я не говорю сейчас о правилах верстки таблиц и т.п. (хотя в принципе и в этих случаях тире обычно с пробелами).

Comment: Для дефисного написания тут нет никаких оснований. Через дефис пишуься слова, обозначеющие **один** объект (диван-кровать, ракета-носитель и т.д.)
Тире, строго говоря, здесь тоже не является регламентированным знаком. Но все-таки по аналогии:   

§ 178. Тире ставится между двумя словами для обозначения пределов пространственных, временных или количественных (в этом случае тире заменяет по смыслу слова «от... до»), например: 
...
§ 179. Тире ставится между двумя или несколькими именами собственными, совокупностью которых называется какое-либо учение, научное учреждение и т. п. 
(Правила-56)

Comment: Внесу уточнение: между цифрами при верстке обычно используется среднее (чуть короче обычного) тире без пробелов. Между словами — тире без пробелов (обычное или длинное).

Comment: >>>Между словами — тире без пробелов (обычное или длинное).<<<
Разве, если между словами используется тире, не всегда ставятся пробелы вокруг тире? Вообще, по-моему, тире всегда окружается пробелами. Если не так, приведите, пожалуйста, правило и примеры.

Comment: Между словами - всегда. Между цифрами - без пробелов или с очень "короткими" отступами. Но это не орфографические разговоры, это вопросы верстки.

Answer (score 0):

"*Цена-качество*" уже настолько устойчивое выражение, что, как мне кажется, может рассматриваться как одно слово (типа *купля-продажа*). Поэтому дефис и без пробелов (§79-1).